# WordPress .htaccess is automatically rewrite after creating post or pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress site which has stopped working when creating any new post or pages. I found .htaccess file is automatically rewrite when i create any new post or page through admin. It adds some extra characters in .htacces file which stops my site. Please suggest me to remove this bug.

Comment: Quick fix maybe. Upgrade your wordpress install and change .htaccess permissions to 444.

Comment: I have updated version of WordPress and tried to change .htaccess permission but still change the permission automatically. And i deleted .htaccess file from root folder but automatically create new .htaccess file with 755 permission.

Comment: Then change it to 444. A file should not have 755. Also are you sure your site is not hacked?